# Representing a game world, alternative to dynamic casting?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a game but first I need a way to represent the world that can hold players and items

I'm currently representing it as a `2D vector of <Entity>` where Entity is a base class

Players and Items both derive from "Entity" class

Players and Items do not share common function except for maybe, a function that'll print their "information"

Dynamic casting will be needed, but I've read that it's a code smell as it is a school project, I wanna implement it in the "best way" possible

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Why do players and items derive from the same thing when they don't share common behavior? Review your modeling. Two unrelated things shouldn't be related.

Comment: When you think you need dynamic cast, the correct answer is usually virtual functions.

Comment: @Mat I need them to derive from the same class because I want to store both of them in the same array, what should I look into ?

Comment: Why do you want them in the same array if they're not meant to be used the same way?

Comment: My players will be able to move in that array, however there will be "items" placed randomly and when players encounter an item they will be able to pick it up which is why I want to put both of them in the same array

Comment: You're missing some abstraction here. When a game character moves from one area of the map to the other, the code object doesn't move in memory. The code object might have its map coordinates change. Maybe think about having a map, made of cells/tiles. Cells/tiles have coordinates and can contain a list of items and other stuff. Player objects have a location that points to a tile.

Comment: You can store a `std::variant` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant ; Or you could store a `tile` class in the vector, which has separate lists for items and players on that position (if there can be several on the same tile) ; if you do it with inheritance instead the big question is, how you want to distinguish between both; depending on the answer, there are several ways, how to do inheritance specifically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you've gotten so far, you can tell that at least some people think you should use separate arrays, and your argument for why it's one array doesn't really make sense, but sure...

The basic problem is that Items just flat out don't share a set of actions with Players, and the things you would do to each are different as well.

But if you insist on putting them into the same array, then you're going to need to detect what it is and end up with a typecast. Or do some polymorphism. For instance:

```
class Entity {
...
    virtual void doSomeItemAction() {}
    virtual void doSomePlayerAction() {}
}

class Item: public Entity {
...
     void doSomeItemAction() override { ... }
}
```

et cetera.

Frankly, I wouldn't do it this way. I'd use separate vectors. But your two choices are detect type and typecast or do weird polymorphism that doesn't really fit your problem space, but you could make it work.